# Issue adding new xml node

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xslt

I am not understanding why I am not able to create new xml node.

The code is a try to create a new node and update the view.

Even the textContent property I can't catch in my alerts.

Anything wrong on the code? Another doubt. Why does not it work on IE?

Full Code: http://jsfiddle.net/AdKfp/1/

My XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<form>
    <column id='1' name='Field1' value='Value 1' />
    <column id='2' name='Field2' value='Value 2' />
    <column id='3' name='Field3' value='Value 3' />
    <column id='4' name='Field4' value='Value 4' />
    <column id='5' name='Field5' value='Value 5' />
    <column id='5' name='Field6' value='Value 6' />
  </form>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Fund Infos</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>#</th>
          </tr>

          <xsl:for-each select="form/column">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
              <td><input value="{@value}" /></td>
              <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addNode();" /></td>
              <td><input type="button" value="Remove" /></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
function addNode(){

  alert(xml.textContent);

  newel=xml.createElement("column");
  newel.setAttribute("Name", "New Field");
  newel.setAttribute("Value", "New Value");

  alert(newel.textContent);

  x=xml.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
  x.appendChild(newel);

  alert(x.textContent);

  displayResult();

}
```

Comment: `xml.documentElement.appendChild(newel);`? And your attribute names on javascript snippets should be lower case, as XML files are case sensitive.

Comment: I didn't realize about lower case and it slipped my mind to use documentElement to bind the new node, but I did the changes, but it still not working. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/AdKfp/3/